# Compile typescript project as local module

Tags: angular, typescript, tsc

## tl;dr

Can I have typescript compile different folders as separate libraries, and import the results like a node module?

---

For example, I have a `common` folder with 800 files, and then a few `app` folders (`app1`, `app2`, etc) each with 20+/- files. All of the `app` folders have references to classes/interfaces/etc inside of the `common` folder. The problem is that whenever I compile an `app` folder it also compiles all 800 of the `common` files. This compilation takes too long and I'd really like to avoid it.

I have tested and confirmed this using `tsc --diagnostics --listFiles` in both `common` and `app1`.

I've tried using the `exclude` property in `tsconfig.json` to ignore the `common` folder, but it seems to have no effect. I've also tried multiple configurations of `baseDir`, `paths`, etc. within the `compilerSettings`, but to no avail.

`noResolve` seems to almost achieve what I am looking for, but is that safe??

**Is there a way to compile them separately and avoid recompiling the independent `common` project all the time?**

---

Tech Stack:

- Angular 2.0.1
- SystemJS 0.19.39
- Typescript 2.0.3
- Windows 8.1
- ASP.NET MVC6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate your common folder into a different project call `common`, and make it into a node.js modules, instruction here:

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules

Then in your original project, you do following:

Method 1

```
npm link <folder path of common>
```

Method 2

```
npm install <folder path of common> --save
```

Method 1 is easier to use as update to `common` is automatically reflected in the main project and don't have to worry about updating.

Method 2 is good if you plan to later publish it as a standalone npm package. However update to `common` will require manual update step in the main project.

In your `common` folder, make sure you create a `.npmignore` file. Let say your `common` project have following structure:

```
.                                                                                                                                                               
├── index.d.ts
├── index.js                                                                                                                                                    
├── lib/  <--- compiled location                                                                                                                               
├── node_modules                                                                                                                                                
├── package.json                                                                                                                                                
├── src/                                                                                                                                                         
├── tsconfig.json                                                                                                                                               
├── typings                                                                                                                                                     
└── typings.json
```

then your `.npmignore` should look like following:

```
.DS_Store
.git
.gitignore
examples
node_modules
npm-debug.log
src
tsconfig.json
typings
typings.json
```

You can check out my [ng2-simple-mq](https://github.com/J-Siu/ng2-simple-mq) as an example.

Comment: I don't know if this would actually fix my problem. I can bundle the whole thing up just fine, it just does it in an inefficient way. I want to see if the vanilla Typescript compiler can handle compiling a "project" as a local module.

Comment: @JimmyBoh Actually there is an easier way.

Comment: @JimmyBoh Updated.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think of using `npm install <localpath>`, that's a decent idea. But this would result in nested `node_module` folders (root project level and within each `app` folder), which might not be a bad thing. Also how would updates need to be handled (call `npm install` again, bump version, etc)?

Comment: @JimmyBoh (1) The `common` project would be better sitting outside of the app project folder. So it become standalone library project. (2) Version bump works, or manually deleting it from app's node_modules works too.

Comment: I see. I guess using `npm link ../common` from any of the `app` folders is also an option, similar approach.

Comment: @JimmyBoh Yes, actually `npm link` seems simpler to use as update of `common` package is automatically reflected, no extra step needed once it is setup. I will update answer. :D

Comment: While it doesn't seem possible to do with pure TypeScript, I guess using `npm link` is the best way to go. Thanks @John Sui!