# How to use TypeScript references for Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

My Firebase project is all TypeScript. I have a `core` lib that I use in order to share some of the code between my Cloud Functions and my Web App. Maintaining `core` as an npm package started to become really cumbersome because in order to make a small change in the code and test it in a deployment, I'd have to build the lib, bump versions, publish it, etc. For that reason I decided to migrate to [TypeScript Project References](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html).

My directory structure looks something like:

```
./functions
./webapp
./lib
  ./core
```

And then `functions` has a `tsconfig.json` file with:

```
"references": [
   {"path": "../lib/core"}
]
```

Building the `functions` project with `tsc --build` works, but the dependency on core in the built `*.js` function files ends up being:

```
const core_1 = require("../../../lib/core");
```

So, after `firebase --deploy`, firebase will complain:

```
⚠  functions[testFunction(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.
```

I assume this is happening because of that require.

I've looked at using `prepend: true` on the references, but I don't know if this will be counterproductive, since my `core` project depends on `firebase-functions` and other firebase libs.

Is there a way to have `tsc` bring in the referenced projects into the structure of `dist` (the output directory)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858993/compile-typescript-project-as-local-module